# How to update VS Code GOPATH when running my code in VS Code terminal?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

In Ubuntu, I have changed my GOPATH variable via bash terminal. In VS Code it is now showing updated path with `Go: current GOPATH` command.

However, when I run `go run *.go` I get an error that it can not find my package from my old GOPATH. I tried disabled Go extension, but the error is the same. I even set my new GOPATH in settings.json in VS Code.

Comment: where did you "update your GOPATH"? its probable that the file you updated it in (.eg maybe ~/.bashrc) has not been reloaded by your terminal session, if it is in ~/.bashrc for example that would usually get loaded the next time you launch a terminal, you could force the execution by typing `. ~/.bashrc` in terminal, you can also type echo $GOPATH in terminal to verify what value it is using

Comment: I changed it with command in bash`export GOPATH=/media/mygocode`. When I type `go env` I can see it is updated.

Comment: However, now I reopened my terminal and it showed again old GOPATH. So I updated it only temporarily? How to make this change persistent?

Comment: yes, if you just run the command in terminal it will be temporary - just the life of that session - I would suggest add it to the bottom of ~/.bashrc, then you can exec the file with `. ~/.bashrc` for immediate change - it will then get run every time you launch a terminal

Comment: I put `export GOPATH=/path/to/my/custom/workspace` in my `.bashrc`. Restarted for loading in session and started VS Code. Voila, it works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The recommended approach is, since Go module in 1.11, it is recommended to use a `go.mod` in your project.
So `unset GOPATH`.

See "[Golang Environment – GOPATH vs go.mod](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/golang-environment-gopath-vs-go-mod/)" from Otavio Ehrenberger

That, and:

```bash
go clean -cache
go clean -testcache
go build
```

Now you can try again your `go run` command again.